# When I'm using VMware Workstation, Can I access the localhost of my Guest server from the Host?

Tags: apache, vmware, centos, apache-config

I'm newbie to the linux and apache server configuration so please give me some advice.

I installed VMware in my WinXP and installed CentOS5 to it. After I set up Apache server in my CentOS, I can access that server from my CentOS(of course). But is there a way to access that from my Windows?

I think that is definitely possible if some ip address and apache configuration is set properly...

Comment: Consequently, this is more of a ServerFault question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into the device settings on the VM and make sure your ethernet adapter is set to bridged.

Refresh the eth0 interface in centOS and run 'ifconfig' to get the IP address.

At that point you should be able to just throw the IP into a browser on the host machine and be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the ethernet adapter to bridge as you said, but I can't access the server in guest from my host. And I tried the reversed one:access the server in host from my guest, and it worked. So I think it would be something wrong with my server configuration in the guest.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been ripping my hair out over why I can't reach my webserver.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure you have added a VMNetwork, a network adapter to the VM, and that the VMNetwork is one that is bound to being able to use your Host network card. If you have a dhcp server (common from a household DSL router), then your VM Guest should get an IP address from it. Then you should be able to start apache and then browse to it by the dhcp address received.

Comment: just run ifconfig and connect using the net addr of eth0

Comment: adding to the above, run ipconfig from the command promt (note typo in prev suggestion) and have VMWARE network adapter set to NAT